# How do you get HbbTV browser logs from a JVC Android TV?

Tags: android, adb, hbbtv

I'm in the process of exploring the capabilities of HbbTV on a JVC Android TV. While there is [an example application for logging to the screen](https://developer.hbbtv.org/tutorials/basic-screen-logger/), there are times when the application I write does not run at all. This is despite it working in a desktop browser. The deliver mechanism is a dummy DVB-T multiplex with the application URL encoded. I can see requests to the server being made. The HbbTV example "hello world" application successfully runs this way.

Is there a good way to get a hold of the browser logs for an HbbTV application on an Android TV? I've tried adb and get a streaming log back but cannot see anything from the browser rendering the application.

For background, this is for a master's research topic rather than a production application.

Comment: Not sure how HbbTV is implemented on Android but if it is rendered in a web browser [Chrome remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) may be the way to go.

Comment: Off the top of my head (Not in a position to test it) , but since it's an android system, then I'd try to see if you can get at it with Adb.  On my Android T95 TV box I went into the settings, tapped on the build number 7 or so times to unlock developer mode, then within developer mode switched on "USB Debugging" which then allowed me to use the Adb tools to access the command line.  I don't have a JVC TV (Mine are all Vestel) so I don't know if it will definately work or not however.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Unfortunately the remote debugging finds the device but NOT a Chrome session.

ADB is already working. I'm just struggling to see anything useful in the logs.